# jQuery Validate - Numbers with commas into specific range

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

I am using jQuery Validator to validate my form, however I need to be able to validate numbers with commas ex:

```
10,5
1,5
```

and into the range of :

```
[0, 60]
```

So until now **I am only being able to validate numbers with commas**, using this custom Regex :

```
       $.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(\d+|\d+,\d{1,2})$/i.test(value);
        }, "Number is invalid: Please enter a valid number.");


       $('.my-form').validate({
            rules: {
                "my-field-input": {
                    required: true,
                    regex: "Required number"
                }
            }
        });
```

So at the end I would like that user can only input numbers with commas and into range of 0 .. 60 ex:

```
10,5
1,5
60
50,5
```

And **step is : 0,5**

Any suggestion ? Should I keep doing it with jQuery Validator or create some custom code ? thanks!

Comment: What's the issue with the code you have?

Comment: I would like to validate the range also! my code only validate numbers with commas

Comment: Did you research at all? http://blog.rebuildall.net/2011/03/02/jquery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the number is is one digit number or if it is two digit the first one is less than 6, or it is equal to 60

```
^([0-9]{1}|(([0-5]{1}[0-9]?))(,\d{1})?|60)$
```

here is the fiddle:
https://regex101.com/r/cW3rB7/4

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works, but it doesn't match 0 or 60 ... user have to be able to enter that too..

Comment: @LMS It had errors, I have edited it you might have copied it before changes. now it should be working.

Comment: @LMS please check fiddle for easier testing

Comment: Yea I just checked again ! I would like to be able to enter only "0" or only "60" also in this interval : [ '0' ... '0,1', ... '0,2' .. '20' .... '60' ]

Comment: you mean a number 0-60 without comma?

Comment: I think you didn't understand what am looking for yet! in normal float numbers here how numbers look into the interval of [0, 60]

[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ..... 1, 2, 3, ....10, 20, 50 ... ,60 ]

however using commas will not consider the input as number, so am trying to make it possible to format the numbers using commas and into the interval [0..... 60] I hope it makes sense now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105991/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-lms).

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you almoset hade it

^(\d{1}|[0-5]{1}\d{1}|5[0-9]+,\d{1,2}|60)$